# Help identifying a bonsai?

Tags: identification, bonsai

I have recently been gifted a bonsai; it's actually from Marks & Spencers in the UK, but frustratingly it doesn't have any kind of information what the species is.

The leaves seem a bit darker and thicker than a ficus, and the bark almost reminds me of an apple tree? It also has produced these small, white blooms.

I'm really keen to find out what it is, especially so I can properly handle things like soil pH and find an appropriate fertilizer!

I've attached some photos here as well.

[image: Overview of the bonsai]

[image: Close up of the bark]

[image: Close up of bonsai leaves]

[image: Close up of bonsai leaves with emerging flowers]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Ehretia microphylla* better known as Fukien Tea tree, it is a popular tropical bonsai. This means that it cannot be exposed to frost. For more detailed care instruction please see for example [here](https://www.dallasbonsai.com/care-guides/fukien-tea.html).

Comment: Excellent, thank you! I knew you were exactly right the minute I looked it up and saw the leaves.

Comment: Great, you are welcome! Good luck with this bonsai tree.

Comment: "Fukien Tea tree" - there really is no need for language like that :-)