# Name this bonsai tree species please?

Tags: identification, bonsai

I bought this bonsai tree recently and I'm wondering what species it is. As you can see from the picture it has white flowers. Thanks in advance.(https://i.stack.imgur.com/CNc15.jpg)

Comment: Can you post a better picture of the label, especially the Japanese?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it is *Ehretia microphylla* or **Fukien Tea tree** in English. It is a popular species for indoor bonsai. See [here](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/47222/help-identifying-a-bonsai) for a previous post about the same bonsai species.

Comment: Yes! Thank you!